# Returning back the node name not the type/label?

Tags: redis, cypher, redisgraph

if I have the following node :

```
> graph.query graph1 'create (jim:node)'
```

how do I query and get back the "jim"-value, not the 'node'-label

Answer (score 2):

"jim" is not a value. It's a reference to the node you just created for future usage.

ex:

```
create (jim:node)
create (jack:node)
create (jim)-[:KNOWS]->(jack)
```

If you want to return the node you have created, you can simply write

```
create (jim:node) return jim
```

But keep in mind that it will not retrun the value "jim", it will return the node you capture with the reference "jim"

If you want to assign the value "jim" to the node, you must create a property on that node to store the value :

```
create (a:node {name:"Jim"}) return a.name
```